# Python: Name "extract_training_sample" is not defined error

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory

I am a Python newbie currently looking into Crash Course Ai #5 [How to Make an AI read your handwriting (LAB).](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6nGCGYWMObE)

Running [Step 1.2](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1NyYH1EPpaJlMBLK0fcKYz4icaD1SNSLK#scrollTo=vDj9tyEAMVn5&forceEdit=true&sandboxMode=true&uniqifier=1) gives me *NameError: name 'extract_training_samples' is not defined.

Tried so far: 1) updated pip version to 20.0.2 and installed emnist python package

2) tried an additional line of code: *from emnist import extract_training_samples* but got a *ModuleNotFound* error.

Feedback appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

OK, very simple solution! 
You just forgot the "s". 
I find myself running into that problem all the time when coding. Whenever I run into a Name Error, the first thing I do is check my spelling!

your code:
x, y = extract_training_sample('letters')

the code on the website:
extract_training_samples('letters')

Cheers,